# group matching in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, string

How can I get a javascript match text if I had some test example like :

```
someblablatext?someotherimportanttext
```

How can I capture everything after question mark sign (?). And alert it?

Was looking [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp) didn't find some examples on this type of expressions? do I need to use group matching for this. Never used regex in javascript so far I did in Java many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this. Simply use string.split() function, e.g.:

```
var yourString = "someblablatext?someotherimportanttext"
alert(yourString.split('?')[1]);
```

A while ago I heard that if you can use a string function instead of regex, then you probably should,. I did some benchmarking and it seems that string functions are very fast and in many cases faster than regexes (not talking about complex examples, just about something as simple as this).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`regexp.exec(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

```
/\?(.*)$/.exec("someblablatext?someotherimportanttext")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers solve your issue but to be exact at your question (How can I capture everything AFTER question mark sign (?)), here is the regex you are looking for `/(=?\?.*)/`

`=?` means if followed by, `\?` mean question mark character, `.*` everything. To make them work you need to group them with `()`. That's it.